# Swift 4 - Issue with constraints on iPhone

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am having some major issues with my constraints, all I did was select add missing constraints and it looks fine in my storyboard and on an iPad like so,

[image]

But when I run it on iPhone, it looks like this:

[image]

What do I need to add to fix this issue...this is what I got so far:

[image]

Comment: `Username.leading = 283`. That means 283 points from the left. The width of that iPhone is 375pt. What do you expect? Why don't you just use a center constraint? You don't need to add anything. You have to *remove* the constraints you already have and think carefully which constraints you have to add.

Comment: add missing cons is advanced step , first learn how to create constraints yourself , and after being experienced use it and edit them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't relay only on **Add missing constraints** , you have to make your edits after applying them

I see some constraints with leading

> 949,344 and 283+

and this may exceed width of some iphone screens

---

Simply remove any leading and trailing , and centerX the items with width constraints

also using UIStackView is good for the lower textfields

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your problem with the constrains in my opinion for this type of layout is to embed your views in to Stack View. With Stack View you can easy center this views in to Screen by adding some costrains to the Stack View. With Stack Views if you need some adjustment you can do it only with few mouse clicks.

1. Select all your views
2. Click embed in the Stack View
3. Delete constrians that you don't need
4. Adjust alignment, distribution and spacing
5. Add trailing, leading and heigh constrian

Now it should looks good.